# Mercurial Plugin, Jenkins and Cloudbees

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, cloudbees

I'm trying to run jenkins on my project hosted in bitbucket using mercurial.  I have the following settings for mercurial:

```
repository url:  http://bitbucket.org/myuser/myproject
credentials:  username with password    (I have my bitbucket username / password)
Revision Type:  branch
Revision:  default
```

When I run the build, I'm getting the following:

```
Started by user Me / Me
Building remotely on bec9ae7e (lxc-fedora17 m1.xlarge hi-speed xlarge) in workspace     /scratch/jenkins/workspace/myproject
$ hg --config ******** clone --rev default --noupdate http://bitbucket.org/myuser/myproject /scratch/jenkins/workspace/myproject
abort: http authorization required
ERROR: Failed to clone http://bitbucket.org/myuser/myproject
ERROR: Failed to clone http://bitbucket.org/myuser/myproject
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm not finding seeing where my appropriate credentials are being sent over.  Plus, not sure what all of these config things are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--config ********` is a masked version of the command-line option defining authentication. The form you quote seems to be for SSH private key authentication, which contradicts your claim that the specified credentials were a username/password pair (which would produce several `--config` options, some not masked). So I would double-check your credentials.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to figure.  Where do you have it use a username / password on the Jenkins interface.  My credentials use username / password

Comment: Depends on how you created the credentials in the system _Credentials_ UI: as SSH private key, or username + password.